# Is there a way to return the name of the selected bookmark in Power BI? Something like the selectedvalue() command

Tags: powerbi, bookmarks

Hi I'm looking for a DAX code that can return the name of the selected bookmark. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve vs your attempted solution? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just need to create a measure that returns the name of the selected bookmark

Comment: But is it too display the bookmark name on the page or do you want to use it for some other logic?

Comment: Need to use it for some other logic

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There is no DAX function to do exactly that.

There are (tedious) workarounds that would allow you to do that. One could be to have a table that would have all names of your bookmarks, then each of your bookmark would set a page level filter on that table (to the value equal to the name of your bookmark). That way, you can get `SELECTEDVALUE` from the filtered table of bookmark names.

Since you refuse to elaborate on your question, that's all I can give you.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!